# Отловить клик на кнопке в QWebEngineView

Tags: qt, qt5, qwebengine

Добрый день!

Можно ли отловить клик на каком-либо html-элементе страницы (например div), отображаемой в QWebEngineView?

Использую Qt 5.10.0.

Comment: Через javascript можно, как на любом сайте

Comment: Уточню. Мне нужно это отловить в коде c++.

Answer (score 0):

У нас в проекте реализовывали через такую сущность как helper.
Для проброса сигналов вам надо создать QWebChannel и задать его вашей страницы в QWebEngineView.
Далее зарегистрировать объект в канале.
И после создать в html документе.

```
QWebChannel *channel = new QWebChannel(view->page());
view->page()->setWebChannel(channel);
Helper *helper = new Helper(this);
channel->registerObject(QStringLiteral("Helper"), helper);

    new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
        var widget = channel.objects.Helper;

    });
```

Теперь при вызови в JS методов widget они будут отрабатывать в C++.

JS:

```
vat str = "myStr"
widget.print(str)
```

С++:

```
void Helper::print(const QString& str)
{
 qDebud() << str << endl;
}
```